# In windows cmd, is this an output redirection?

Tags: windows, cmd

When I run Windows cmd, the first line goes like this:

```
C:\Users\Alex>
```

Is '>' in the first line an output redirection operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `>` is indeed a redirection operator, along with `<` and `|`. However, in this case the greater than sign `>` is part of the prompt.

At that command prompt, type this and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (don't worry, I'm including how to put it back the way it is later):

```
C:\Users\Alex>prompt $P$F
```

You'll see that now the prompt has a closing parenthesis `)` instead of `>`.

```
C:\Users\Alex)
```

Now type

```
C:\Users\Alex)prompt $P$$
```

The prompt now changes to

```
C:\Users\Alex$
```

To set it back where we started, just type

```
C:\Users\Alex$prompt $P$G
```

You'll see

```
C:\Users\Alex>
```

To see what options are available, type `prompt /?` or `help prompt` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a *prompt*, and it is printed by `cmd` itself in order to show that it `cmd` is ready to accept a command (and to show the current directory). However, in the commands that *you* type in, `>` is indeed the output redirection operator.

Answer (score 1):

In that case when you typed `cmd` Thats just the command prompt which ends with a `>`. But '>' is the output redirection operator when you used for example in this manner. I have purposely hihglighted the prompt and the command differently.

**C:\Users\Alex>**`dir > a.txt`